# Regular Expression word matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a word in a string using `\b`

For example

I want to match the word `abcde`
in the string `xyz abcde ddd` and `xyz abcde.html ddd`. I am using a regular expression `\babcde\b` and what I want is to match only the first string but not the second since it contain `abcde.html`. But this regex matches both of them.

How can I achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead to avoid matching any `abcde` followed by a period and alphanumerics:

```
\babcde\b(?!\.\w+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR4fS1/1)

The `(?!\.\w+)` negative look-ahead makes checks, but does not cosume the presence of the period and alphanumerics, and if they are present, no match is returned. You can make it more generic by replacing `\w+` with `\S+` (1 or more non-whitespace characters).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a positive look-ahead

```
\babcde\b(?=\s)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oA7rX0/1)

The `(?=\s)` check any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]` after `babcde`

Answer (score 0):

```
\babcde(?=.*?\b)
```

A look ahead is what you need.
Here's an example fiddle:
http://refiddle.co/2ing

Note: If by "second string" you mean the ".html" part then this answer will work, but if you meant the whole second string of "xyz abcde.html ddd" then [Wiktor Stribiżew has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472901/regular-expression-word-matching/32472947#32472947).